# Convert result set to Seq[(String,String)] using Scala and anorm in play

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

I have tried to get result set from mySQL database table using anorm. here is my code.

```
package models
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
import scala.collection.mutable._
import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._

    case class Brand(id: Int, name: String)


        object Brand {

             /**
            * Parse a Brand from a ResultSet
            */
            val simple = {
                get[Int]("m_brand.idbrand") ~
                get[String]("m_brand.brandName") map {
                case id~name => Brand(id, name)
                }
            }

            /**
            * Construct the Map[String,String] needed to fill a select options set.
            */
            def options: Seq[(String,String)] = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
                 SQL("select * from m_brand order by brandName").as(Brand.simple *).
                    foldLeft[Seq[(String, String)]](Nil) { (cs, c) => 
                     c.id.fold(cs) { id => cs :+ (id.toString -> c.name) }
                }
            }

}
```

I tried change code with some experiments but not worked.

But I got this error

> Read from stdout:
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\Project_VendorM8\app\models\Brand.scala:69: type
>   mismatch; Read from stdout: found   :
>   scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type Read from stdout: required:
>   scala.collection.mutable.Seq[(String, String)]
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\Project_VendorM8\app\models\Brand.scala:69: type
>   mismatch;  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type  required:
>   scala.collection.mutable.Seq[(String, String)] Read from stdout:
>   foldLeftSeq[(String, String)] { (cs, c) => 
>         foldLeftSeq[(String, String)] { (cs, c) =>  Read from stdout: ^

Comment: Using Anorm 2.5, you can use `val parser = anorm.Macro.parser[Brand]("m_brand.idbrand", "m_brand.brandName")`; See http://cchantep.github.io/anorm/#generated-parsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked in the comments, would a simpler solution not be just to use map and write:

```
def options: Seq[(String,String)] = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL("select * from m_brand order by brandName").as(simple *)
    .map( b => (b.id.toString, b.name))
    .toSeq
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
foldLeft[Seq[(String, String)]](Nil)
```

to

```
foldLeft(Seq.empty[(String, String)])
```

Comment: I did your change but after that I got this error.
`value fold is not a member of Int
Read from stdout: c.id.fold(cs) { id => cs :+ (id.toString -> c.name) }
                     c.id.fold(cs) { id => cs :+ (id.toString -> c.name) }
Read from stdout: ^  `

Comment: Check the type of `id`

Comment: I don't see the purpose of the `.foldLeft`. Using `.map` on the result list should be ok.